# how to find the available memory before store a file?

Tags: c++, memory-management, file-io

I want to save some files in a particular folder (/tmp/) using C++ code. 
Before store the file

1. I need to check whether enough memory is available or not. If not, I need to delete the oldest file from the storage and then I need to store a new one.
2. I also need to know the stored file details in my code to access them.

My implementation is:

```
std::map<string IfileName, int iDetail>
```

I created a Map instance and whenever I create a file data, I stored the details in the map. 
Problems with the map are:

1. Map automatically sort the filename. So I am not able to identify the oldest file.
2. Suppose, file is deleted in the storage, then also map has the detail about that file.

Comment: I guess, when you said "memory" you meant disk space. Am I right?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi yes . sorry for the wrong  word.

Comment: TOCTOU. Create the file, and expand it to the desired size, if it fails try to free up storage and try again.

Answer (score 0):

For the first your question try to read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/822zd880.aspx). And about second part of your question. Why you do not want to use vector of pairs. In this case you can use push_back.

Comment: Vector are good but they dont have find method to directly search the File content . i need to search it using separate code to get the file detail value.

Comment: You can try to use std::find method. The only point is that you need to play around with it... But it is only a suggestion :) Or, I just noticed that int is a description, you can write your own find function.

Answer (score 0):

At some point I used a combination of a map and deque to solve a similar problem. The trick is that each value_type (in both map and deque) need to be extended with cross pointers. So that when you run map.find() using a certain key, the value that you receive has a pointer to an element in the deque. And vice versa. To locate the oldest (LRU) file you just execute deque.pop_back(), dereference the pointer that you get into the map, view the details and decide if you need to remove one more file or not.